# Chain id error while creating a new network custom RPC in metamask connecting private network in virtual machine

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, poa, aws, chainid

I have a dought related to the.  Blockchain topic

Sir.  I am creating a private blockchain POA
using geth
Using virtual machine
In between, I am connecting it to the metamask by creating custom RPC  URL
Whose format is
http:// ip address : port
So now it is asking for the chain id  so
What should  be the chain id
As it gives error ike:
Could not fetch chain id . Is yourRPCURLcorrect?
Please help sir
Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.